# segfault at 0 ip (null) error 14 when trying to access an array of structs using copy_to_user function

Tags: c, arrays, linux, struct, linux-kernel

Please bear with it's been a while since I programmed in C.  I'm trying to move an array of structs from kernel space into user space.  Below is the error that I'm seeing in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
userspace[5091]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff21250d00 error 14 in userspace[400000+5000]`.
```

The flow of my code is declaring an array of structs on the user side passing that address to the kernel side.  From the kernel side using that user space address I copy an array of structs to that user space address.  Then back in user space I try to iterate through and print the values from that array of structs.  That's where I get a seg fault.

header.h

```
#define MAX_CONTS             100

typedef struct cont_struct {
   int id;
   u32 pid;
} __attribute__((packed)) cont_struct;
```

userspace.c

```
 include "header.h"

 cont_struct conts[MAX_CONTS];
 //cont_struct *conts = (cont_struct *)malloc(MAX_CONTS * sizeof(cont_struct));
 memset(conts, 0, sizeof(conts));
```

I pass the value of `conts` to the kernel side using the proc file system.  I have verified that it is correctly passed.  Below is the kernel code where I try to copy an array of structs to user space using the `copy_to_user` function.  `conts` is the user space address.

kernelspace.c

```
 include "header.h"

 cont_struct kern_conts[MAX_CONTS];
 kern_conts[0].pid = 111;
 kern_conts[0].id = 1;
 kern_conts[1].pid = 222;
 kern_conts[1].id = 2;

 // conts is the value passed from userspace
 if ( copy_to_user((void *)conts, kern_conts, sizeof(conts)) ){
     printk("error\n);
 }
```

Later on I call the code below in user space to iterate through array of structs to print off the values.  Even when I set the end condition of the `for loop` to lower than 100 it still seg faults.  It is also garbage values so I'm pretty sure it's not copying the data correctly.

userspace.c

```
//by this point I hope the array of structs has been properly copied from kernel space to user space
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < MAX_CONTS; i++)
    {
     fprintf(fout, "id: %u pid: %u\n", conts[i].id, conts[i].pid);
   }
```

My first question is that am I declaring the arrays of struct correctly?  I've seen stuff on this forum where people are using the malloc method when working with arrays of structs.  I've tried both ways of declaration on each side but that didn't work either.  The array of structs is populated/manipulated on the kernel side.  Later on in the client side when I try to iterate through and print the values, at the end of iterating through the array it throws the error mentioned above.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show `copy_to_user()`; otherwise the problem cannot be solved given the information.

Comment: it is in the if statement.  thanks.

Comment: it's a kernel api it's not anything i wrote. you can read up on it here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-kernel-memory-access/

Comment: What is the exact type of `conts` in the kernel module?

Comment: The segfault in your title doesn't seem to match the one in the body? Also: if `conts` is a value passed from userspace, that makes it a pointer, not an array. So `sizeof(conts)` is just going to be the size of a pointer, not the size of the array. You need to use a count. Don't know if that's **the** bug, but it's **a** bug, anyway.

Comment: The segfault is appearing in userspace code, of which you show almost nothing.  GDB should show you the line where this segfault occurs.